# Given a Dictionary of Words Determine the Order of the Letters

Tags: python, dictionary, directed-acyclic-graphs, topological-sort

The exact problem statement is this: given a dictionary of words sorted according to some unknown ordering of letters, determine the total order of the letters. It is guaranteed that any inputs provided have a total order and that the order can be found.

From what I have read about this type of problem, it would seem that the correct approach to solving this problem is to build a directed acyclic graph and then perform a topological sort on the graph. Furthermore, there are two ways to implement topological sort (that I am aware of). One of these uses a depth-first search, and this is how I chose to implement my algorithm.

My program works for the small number of test cases provided (and any that I can come up with), but fails for the test cases that are used to verify the correctness of my program. Unfortunately, I cannot access these test cases, or I would have an easier time debugging my program.

Would anybody be willing to suggest some refinements to my code? Is there some other approach to this problem? Also, does anybody know of a way to generate good test cases? The test cases that I have come up with have been inadequate to finding where my program is incorrect. An ideal test case would be a dictionary of words on which a total ordering is guaranteed to exist and be obtainable.

I think the problem is in the way I build my directed acyclic graph.

```
from sets import Set
from copy import copy

#Hash table representation of directed acyclic graph.
DAG = {}
#Set of all vertices with no incoming edges
noIncomingEdges = Set()
#Any array (initially empty) which will contain the total order
#of the letters used to sort the dictionary
sortedLetters = []

class VertexList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.outgoing = Set()
    def addOutgoingEdge(self, edge):
        self.outgoing.add(edge)
    def removeOutgoingEdge(self, edge):
        self.outgoing.remove(edge)

def buildDAG(words):
    numWords = len(words)
    for i in range(numWords - 1):
        #Get two consecutive words from the dictionary
        w1 = words[i]
        w2 = words[i + 1]
        lenw1 = len(w1)
        lenw2 = len(w2)
        #If the first word is longer than the second, pad the first words
        #by taking the last letter in the first words and appending it   until
        #both words are of equal length.
        #As an example:
        #       a       -->     aa
        #       ab      -->     ab
        #The algorithm for building the DAG should now be able to see that
        #a comes before b.
        if lenw1 < lenw2:
            while len(w1) < lenw2:
                w1 = w1 + w1[lenw1 - 1]
        n = lenw2
        for j in range(n):
            #If the DAG doesn't have a vertex for a given letter, add it.
            #Also, add it to the list of nodes with no incoming edges.
            if not DAG.has_key(w1[j]):
                DAG[w1[j]] = VertexList()
                noIncomingEdges.add(w1[j])
            if not DAG.has_key(w2[j]):
                DAG[w2[j]] = VertexList()
                noIncomingEdges.add(w2[j])
            #Compare corresponding letters in the two consecutive words. If
            #The letter in the first word is different from the letter in the
            #second word, create an edge between the vertex represent the letter
            #from the first word and the vertex for the letter in the second
            #word.
            if w1[j] != w2[j] and w2[j] not in DAG[w1[j]].outgoing:
                DAG[w1[j]].addOutgoingEdge(w2[j])
                #Remove the vertex for the second letter from the list of
                #vertices with no incoming edges.
                if w2[j] in noIncomingEdges:
                    noIncomingEdges.remove(w2[j])
                break

def visit(v):
    visited = Set()
    if v not in visited:
        visited.add(v)
        vertices = copy.deepcopy(DAG[v])
        for vertex in vertices.outgoing:
            visit(vertex)
        sortedLetters.insert(0, v)

def topologicalSort():
    for vertex in noIncomingEdges:
        visit(vertex)

def answer(words):
    buildDAG(words)
    topologicalSort()
    return ''.join(sortedLetters)
```

Comment: wait if you have a list of words and a dict of those words' (arbitrary) ordering, wouldn't the result just be `sorted(list_of_words, key=ordering_dict.get)`????

Comment: I should clarify. It's not a dictionary in the Python sense of a dictionary. it's just an array of words sorted according to some unknown ordering.

Comment: okay so build the dictionary first.... `ordering_dict = {word:idx for idx,word in enumerate(magic_array)}` then reduce to the previous problem.

Comment: I don't have enough algorithmic expertise to make suggestions about your algorithm, but you should definitely check out [networkx](https://networkx.github.io/). It's a Python package for manipulating graphs of all types and has numerous graph algorithms, including [topological sort](http://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.dag.topological_sort.html#networkx.algorithms.dag.topological_sort).

Comment: Thank you for the recommendation. For this assignment, I am only allowed to use the built-in Python libraries, though.

Comment: Of course, I could always try to copy the code in the library.

Comment: In case it helps debug, I just tried this with a simple test case and got an empty return from word_list = [
    "a",
    "ab",
    "bad",
    "cadr",
    "card",
    "dab"
]

print answer(word_list)

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.  It's in the line

```
if word1[j] != word2[j] and word2[j] not in DAG[word1[j]].outgoing:
```

You need to separate these clauses, because you have to break out of the loop when the two letters differ, even if the second letter *is* in the DAG.  Otherwise, you go on to the next pair of letters, when you should be done comparing these words.

The result is that you get a spurious DAG edge farther down this pair of words.  I started my data set with

```
a
ab
bad
```

The first comparison went fine, adding a->b to the DAG.
In the second comparison, *ab* vs *bad*, we hit the first difference at the fist letter.  However, since b is already in the outgoing list of a, your logic says to go on to the next letter pair.  This adds the edge b->a from the second letters.

This introduces a cycle to the DAG, killing the algorithm.  The code should read

```
if word1[j] != word2[j]:
    if word2[j] not in DAG[word1[j]].outgoing:
        <add edge>
    break
```